# How to set progress of progressBar in ExecutorService? Don't want to use AsyncTask because it is deprecated

Tags: android

I use below code basically to copy a file inside Executor and I want to publish progress during copying data to a file. The problem is progressBar won't update until the copying the file is finished. The progress goes from 0 to 100 percent in one go rather than showing the progress.

```
 int x=0;
        Executor executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
        executor.execute(()->{
            myDataBase.sendJsonToFile(path,"myFile"+".json");
            for(int i=0;i<=100;i++){
                new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(()->{
                    progressbar.setProgress(x);
                });
                x++;
            }
        });
```

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can use the Executor service abstraction like this,**

```
public abstract class AsyncTaskV2<Params, Progress, Result> {

    public enum Status {
        FINISHED,
        PENDING,
        RUNNING
    }

    // This handler will be used to communicate with main thread
    private final Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
    private final AtomicBoolean cancelled = new AtomicBoolean(false);

    private Result result;
    private Future<Result> resultFuture;
    private ExecutorService executor;
    private Status status = Status.PENDING;

    // Base class must implement this method
    protected abstract Result doInBackground(Params params);

    // Methods with default implementation
// Base class can optionally override these methods.
    protected void onPreExecute() {
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Result result) {
    }

    protected void onProgressUpdate(Progress progress) {
    }

    protected void onCancelled() {
    }

    protected void onCancelled(Result result) {
        onCancelled();
    }

    protected boolean isShutdown() {
        return executor.isShutdown();
    }

    @MainThread
    public final Future<Result> execute(@Nullable Params params) {
        status = Status.RUNNING;
        onPreExecute();
        try {
            executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
            Callable<Result> backgroundCallableTask = () -> doInBackground(params);
// Execute the background task
            resultFuture = executor.submit(backgroundCallableTask);

// On the worker thread — wait for the background task to complete
            executor.submit(this::getResult);
            return resultFuture;
        } finally {
            if (executor != null) {
                executor.shutdown();
            }
        }
    }

    private Runnable getResult() {
        return () -> {
            try {
                if (!isCancelled()) {
// This will block the worker thread, till the result is available
                    result = resultFuture.get();

// Post the result to main thread
                    handler.post(() -> onPostExecute(result));
                } else {
// User cancelled the operation, ignore the result
                    handler.post(this::onCancelled);
                }
                status = Status.FINISHED;
            } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
                Log.e("TAG", "Exception while trying to get result" + e.getMessage());
            }
        };
    }

    @WorkerThread
    public final void publishProgress(Progress progress) {
        if (!isCancelled()) {
            handler.post(() -> onProgressUpdate(progress));
        }
    }

    @MainThread
    public final void cancel(boolean mayInterruptIfRunning) {
        cancelled.set(true);
        if (resultFuture != null) {
            resultFuture.cancel(mayInterruptIfRunning);
        }
    }

    @AnyThread
    public final boolean isCancelled() {
        return cancelled.get();
    }

    @AnyThread
    public final Status getStatus() {
        return status;
    }
}
```

Now, just like the asynctask, this class have `onPreExecute()`, `onPostExecute()` and `doInBackground()`. You can publish your progress in `publishProgress()` method.

**Here is how to use it,**

```
new AsyncTaskV2<Void, Integer, Void>() {
            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                super.onPreExecute();
            }

            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(Void unused) {
                myDataBase.sendJsonToFile(path,"myFile"+".json");
                for(int i=0;i<=100;i++){
                    publishProgress(x);
                    x++;
                }
                publishProgress();
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer integer) {
                super.onProgressUpdate(integer);
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Void unused) {
                super.onPostExecute(unused);
            }
        }.execute(null);
```

Comment: Thank you four your answer. Why onPostExecute not get executed(called)? Because I can't dismiss the dialog inside it. Is there anyway to determine how much of the file  copied so as publish progress for that amount? Could you elaborate a little more?

Comment: Ok then, you can check if total progress is 100% or not then you can dismiss the dialog inside the `doInBackground()` on the main thread.

Comment: thanks man , great  smart work ,i have so many asyncs in our android company app and a lot of issues since 34.